# Improving Asp.NET MVC/Javascript url generation readability

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url

I need to generate urls for use in javascript. I don't think my current solution is very readable.

```
//Navigation during load: Id from MVC or hash or zero.
var m_departmentId = <%= ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"] ?? 0 %>;
if(0 == m_departmentId)
{            
    var hash = location.hash;            
    //Only one hash value
    var id = parseInt(hash.substring(2));

    //If it's a real Id, use it.
    if (!isNaN(id)) {
        m_departmentId = id;

    }
}

var gridUrl = '<%= Url.Action("GetEmployees", "Company", new { area = "" }) %>/' + m_departmentId;
```

This script is placed at top of my page javascript where I translate aspnet-variables to js-variables.

Can I get rid of the first javascript?
Can I improve the readability of the last row? Imho it's rather hideous, especially within my page javascript.
Other improvements?

---

**Improvement 1:**

```
var gridUrl = '<%= Url.Content("~/Company/GetEmployees/") }) %>' + m_departmentId;
```

T4MVC didn't work when the action was the default action for the route, because the action was stripped from the path when no action argument was used.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov It's used for the ajax navigation (with deep linking) on that page (explorer like interface with tree and grid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need the JavaScript for the hash. You can't read hashes server-side.

[T4MVC](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC) may help you with the "ugly" URL generation. It will at least get rid of the magic strings (still can't believe they went that route with the UrlHelper).

Comment: This works: 
`var gridUrl = '<%= Url.Action(MVC.Company.GetEmployees()) %>/' + m_departmentId;` 
It's not much better, but it's at least in a sensible order.

Comment: I also tend to use format strings in these situations. I think it adds to the readability, although it's probably overkill here. `String.Format("{0}/{1}", Url.Action(MVC.Company.GetEmployees()), m_departmentId);`

Comment: Ran into a problem with actions named index when I later need to add the id after. The t4mvc-generated url removes /index which later would result in /Controller/Id instead of /Controller/Action/Id.
I had to write it like this `var m_personUrlTemplate = '<%= Url.Content("~/Person/Index/") %>';`